# Spouse visa with long stay student residence permit in France

Tags: france, resident-permit, student-visa, schengen, students

Does a VLS/TS long stay residence permit issued for a student (not research scholar), grant rights to bring his/her partner into France? If so, is the partner allowed to work?

Please mention if this is possible in the first year upon arrival itself.

According to [this](http://www.immigration-professionnelle.gouv.fr/en/new-provisions/sheet/long-stay-visa-equivalent-to-a-residence-permit-vls-ts) link, it may or may not be possible.

> **Permit issued to the family**
>
> *Depending upon the case:*
>
> VLS-TS for "visitors" the first year. This visa does not give
>   authorisation to work. Dispenses with the CAI. Temporary Residence
>   Permit for "visitors" upon renewal.

Please give an update on the current situation. Please note I am a citizen of Sri Lanka.

Comment: afaik (I can't check now) they could theoretically join you in France, but they could not work and you would have to demonstrate that you have adequate resources to support them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. I did this. I did a 2 year engineering degree and my wife lived with me. I showed that I had plenty of resources to support her, and she didn't work. I did not bring her into France later, she was accepted for her long-term visitor's visa at the same time as I was accepted for my student visa. Again, her visa does not allow her to work.

Comment: Hi @Sterling thanks for you response. Is it possible to get a separate student visa for my wife by following a course? What kind of course would she need to apply to get a student visa?